# Calling an express route from within javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have some routes defined, they work fine. I have a text input for searching at the top, and set up the following listener:

```
$('#tags').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && document.getElementById('tags').value != '') {
      loadDrink(document.getElementById('tags').value);
  }
});
```

I was refactoring stuff and came across a snag. I need that search to redirect to `router.get('/find/:name', function (req,res){});`
How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: First off, this isn't Node, this is most likely the client-side (I can tell by the fact that you are using jQuery and document...). Second, how to trigger a route depends on the client-side JS routing framework you are using. So, what are you using?

Comment: Nothing currently. I was checking out Angular and some MEAN stacks, but it was a bit too much overhead for the size of my project. Trying to keep it simple.

Comment: Well, you could use $.get since you're already using jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you right, then you wish to redirect the client to a route at `find/:name` defined on your server.

In that case, do something like this:

```
location.replace('/find/' + name)
```

Or this:

```
location.assign('/find/' + name)
```

`replace` functions more like an HTTP redirect and the current page is not saved in the history (not accessible via the back button). `assign` adds the next page to the history and navigates to it.

Location is a [property of the Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).